# Find string in between two strings using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am using a regular expression for finding string in between two strings

Code:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("EMAIL_BODY_XML_START_NODE"+"(.*)(\\n+)(.*)"+"EMAIL_BODY_XML_END_NODE");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(part);
        if (matcher.find()) {
                      ..........
```

It works fine for texts but when text contains special characters like newline it's break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the pattern such that `.` matches line terminaters as well. To do this you need to use the `DOTALL` flag.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

edit: Sorry, it's been a while since I've had this problem. You'll also have to change the middle regex from `(.*)(\\n+)(.*)` to `(.*?)`. You need to lazy quantifier (`*?`) if you have multiple `EMAIL_BODY_XML_START_NODE` elements. Otherwise the regex will match the start of the first element with the end of the last element rather than having separate matches for each element. Though I'm guessing this is unlikely to be the case for you.

Comment: Sorry, `MULTILINE` does the opposite of what I thought it did. You're really after the `DOTALL` flag.